# Invalid drive specification using XCOPY

Tags: batch-file

I want to run batch file which copy all relevant folders and sub-folders from a remote computer to my client computer.
I am using the following XCOPY command:

```
xcopy "\\Server_Name\C$\folder_X\folder_Y" "C:\Users\\folder_Z" /I /S /Y /D:%mydate%
```

and got "invalid drive specification" upon running the batch file.

(maybe it related: when trying connect manually via windows "run", typing \\Server_Name\C$\
,I got prompt to enter user and password and after that I can enter the relevant folders).

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify *two* backslashes before the server name or just one? ie. "\\server" or "\server"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try mounting your remote drive locally first:

```
net use x: \\Server_Name\C$
```

Then try copying the files from `X:` instead:

```
xcopy x:\folder_X\folder_Y c:\Users\folder_Z ...
```

To unmount:

```
net use x: /delete
```

Comment: And if I want to copy only 1 file and which I know that the file name contain specific letters in the middle of the file name (i.e. ___xyz___)
How do I need to write the Xcopy command?

Comment: Try `xcopy x:\folder_X\folder_Y\*xyz*.* c:\Users\folder_Z ... `.

Comment: You can also try: `xcopy \\NetworkDriveName\dir_src "C:\path\to\dir_dest" /e`

Comment: To be complete: `net use x: \\Server_Name\C$ userpw /user:domain\username`

Answer (score 6):

Using **net use U: "\server\folder"** will reveal if there is an authentication issue:

In such case it will return "The password is invalid for \server\folder."

**Enter the user name for 'server':** {enter your [network] account name}

**Enter the password for server:**    {enter your password}

**The command completed successfully.**

After successful authentication U: is mapped to \server\folder and the xcopy commands should work!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can map a drive, but its the `SMB` connection not responding in a timely manner for `XCOPY` to work.  I found simply `Waking` the `SMB` connection with a `Get-ChildItem` on your target path does the trick, especially when looping through a number of target servers to copy files out ahead of a big change.

```
$WakeSMB = Get-ChildItem "\\\TargetPath"; 
$Exp = "XCOPY /S /E /V /I /K /O /Y ""D:\SourcePath\*.*"" ""\\\TargetPath"""; 
Invoke-Expression $Exp
```

If `Get-ChildItem` doesn't work, there's probably some other port `445/TCP` constraint affecting `SM`B connections i.e. `Port 445` blocked on some remote firewall, or connection/session timed out (default 60 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. I successfully mapped q: to the remote drive as suggested above - I could CD to it - but I still got the "invalid drive specification" message when I ran my script.

The problem turned out to be at the destination end. My script tried to use the D: drive on my local server instead of the E: drive. The clue came when I tried D: in the command prompt and got a 'The device is not ready' message.

I changed my script to copy to E: as intended and now can xcopy (without bothering with the mapping) and have no problem. Well, except my DB restore command isn't working... here we go again...

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xcopy \\server\c$\folder c:\folder`