# Invalid drive specification using XCOPY in a scheduled job in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows, networking

I use SQL Server 2014 on a Windows 2012r2 machine, and I need to copy backup files to another server (2012r2). I read this SO post:

[Invalid drive specification using XCOPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907104/invalid-drive-specification-using-xcopy)

I was able to run the following successfully

```
net use Z: \\SQL02\H$

xcopy F:\BackupTest\*.bak Z:\BackupTest\ /s /d
```

However, I got the "Invalid drive specification" when using the same xcopy code in a scheduled job in the SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to map a drive.  XCopy can use the UNC paths, eg

`xcopy F:\BackupTest\*.bak \\SQL02\H$\BackupTest\ /s /d`

But the SQL Server service account needs permissions.  The 'H$' is an admin share, so the service account or the machine account would need admin permissions on the other server.  If you create a regular share on the other server you can set granular permissions.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Could you be a bit more specific about " service account or the machine account would need admin permissions on the other server"? The "Run as" for xcopy is SQL Server Agent Service Account, which is the only option in the dropdown list. How can I give this account permissions so that there will be no "Invalid drive specification"? Did quite research, but failed to find howto. Thanks!

Comment: I finally got it working. Shrare the BackupTest folder on the other server and use the UNC path without $: `\\SQL02\H\BackupTest`